# How do I stack elements using the object Array index?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

So I'm trying to get the elements in this angular component to cascade on load, I need them in this layout (see image).

How do I write the function in the TS file to pull their index position from the array that is creating the elements and use that to assign css properties position and z-index (index 0 in number 3 position in image)?

[image: stacking cascade example]

Got it like this below!

```
     <div *ngFor="let img of imageURLs, let i = index" class="tap-target">
          <img [alt]="'image' + i" [id]="'image' + i" style="width: 20%; height: auto"
               [src]="img"  class="resize-drag" [ngStyle]="{'z-index': i, 'top': 2 * i + '%', 'left': 2 * i + '%'}">
        </div>
```

Comment: You will find that you will receive more helpful answers if you show what you have tried and where you are stuck specifically in your code. Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Show what you have tried and where you are stuck. When practical post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add z-index in html only

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'z-index': i}">

</div>
```

or if you have list of components

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index" [ngStyle]="{'z-index': i}">

</div>
```

Comment: I added some code above.. is this what you mean? I am still not getting exactly the layout here I was looking for

Comment: can you share the output you are getting, or it will be even better if you can share a stackblitz link

Comment: I got it! to get the cascade effect, I was leaving out the '%' for the top and left values